# how to call Common Lisp codes from JSCL method

Tags: javascript, lisp, common-lisp

[JSCL](https://jscl-project.github.io/) is one of the implementations of Common Lisp(CL).

It covers many of CL features except CLOS, format, etc.

It has its REPL as other CL implementations.

I'd like to know how to call CL codes from JS side.

I'd like to do like this:

```
// set the CL codes as string
var codes = "(defun f1(x) (+ x 1) )
(f1 99)";

// call CL codes from JSCL
JSCL.CL.call(codes);
=> 100
```

I'd like to find such a method in JSCL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New method was exposed.

If you type the following code on the JS console, you will get 12.

`jscl.evaluateString("(* 3 4)")`

Answer (score 2):

You can call Common Lisp function and special forms from the JS console.
You just need to type the following code on the console of the browser.

In the example below, The first code defines the function that returns the value added 1.  And the second code calls the function and print the evaluated value 100.

```
jscl.CL.PRINT.fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.CL.EVAL.fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.packages["COMMON-LISP"].symbols["READ-FROM-STRING"].fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.internals.js_to_lisp("(defun f1(x)(+ x 1))"))))

jscl.CL.PRINT.fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.CL.EVAL.fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.packages["COMMON-LISP"].symbols["READ-FROM-STRING"].fvalue.call(this, jscl.internals.pv, jscl.internals.js_to_lisp("(f1 99)"))))
```